# Changing NAs to zeroes in a ff vector in R

Tags: r, na

Am stuck using the ff package. Here is a sample of data.

```
             col1                col2
90                            
91 21-02-2012 00:00:00 27-02-2009 00:00:00
92 21-02-2012 00:00:00 17-02-2010 00:00:00
93 21-02-2012 00:00:00   
94 21-02-2012 00:00:00                    
95 21-02-2012 00:00:00
```

What the plan was to convert these dates to numbers and then find the number of days between the dates. What I am stuck on is when I convert the dates to numbers naturally enough I get some NAs which is ok. What I would like to do is convert the NAs to the integer 0. Here is the code I tried:

```
tfd<-as.ffdf(tfd) #just to get a sample from my data frame
dats<-as.ff(as.numeric(as.Date(tfd[,1],"%d-%m-%Y")))
dats[is.na(dats)]<-0
```

I get the error:

```
Error in `[<-.ffdf`(`*tmp*`, is.na(dats), value = 0) : 
  value must be ffdf if only one index used
```

I have tried the na.count function but I had no luck. I checked the `ffbase` and `ff` pdfs and nothing. I had a good look through the web and nothing that would help with a `ff` vector.

If anyone has any suggestions that would be great.
Cheers,
Lorcan

Comment: You don't need to convert to numbers to calculate the number of days between each date. An appropriate date format would do that just fine. Also, you would be more likely to get help if you post your data in a format that's easy for others to copy and run in their R session.

Comment: Can you make your question title a bit more informative? That way, next person searching for this sort of problem might have a better chance of finding your post.

Comment: if you apply the "as.Date(tfd[,1],"%d-%m-%Y")" code it converts the date into an easier format. The sample that I have provided is what I am dealing with and what I read into R.

Comment: you can use require(ffbase); tfd$col1 <- with(tfd, ifelse(is.na(col1), 0, col1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheers for the help again, your all to kind. A colleague gave me a suggestion about using the ifelse function in R to fill the blanks before with an integer. I couldn't fill the blanks with a default date, let's say "2006-01-01" but using integers worked perfectly. Here is the code:

```
ffdf1$dates1<-as.ff(ifelse(ffdf1[,3]=="",16000,as.numeric(as.Date(ffdf1[,3],"%d-%m-%Y"))))<br>
```

ffdf1 is the ff data frame that I was using. Instead of 0 I decided to use 16,000. ffdf[,3] is the column that contains the dates. This code will work for the dates I gave in the example in the original question. Hope this helps and sorry if the question confused people,
Cheers,
Lorcan

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the example above

```
# turn data.frame into ffdf
> F <- as.ffdf(Z)

# extract a complete column to RAM
> F[,1]
 [1] "2012-08-02" NA           "2012-08-10" "2012-08-18" "2012-08-01" NA           "2012-08-19" "2012-08-12"
 [9] "2012-08-11" NA

# assign zero to the NAs
> F[is.na(F[,1]),1] <- 0

# check the results
> F[,1]
 [1] "2012-08-02" "1970-01-01" "2012-08-10" "2012-08-18" "2012-08-01" "1970-01-01" "2012-08-19" "2012-08-12"
 [9] "2012-08-11" "1970-01-01"

# you tried to call is.na() directly on an ff object
> is.na(F[[1]])
logical(0)

# compare to 
> is.na(F[,1])
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

# note that all this assumes that the complete column fits into RAM
# if not you need chunking, see ?chunk

> version
               _                            
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32           
arch           x86_64                       
os             mingw32                      
system         x86_64, mingw32              
status                                      
major          2                            
minor          15.2                         
year           2012                         
month          10                           
day            26                           
svn rev        61015                        
language       R                            
version.string R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
nickname       Trick or Treat
```